# How to Reconcile one query with another in MS-ACCESS database with VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datatable, datagridview

I want to reconcile one query with another in the MS-ACCESS database with VB.NET .

So I want to reconcile which is loaddata1 with loaddata2 which is for columns `QTY_STOCK,QTY_STOCKIN,QTY_STOCKOUT`whether it is the same or not

actually I don't need reconciliation if I use loaddata2 directly but the problem is that I can't update in the column `SACK_NUMBER`.

Please guide so that I take the correct method.

Thanks

```
 Private Function CreateConnection() As OleDbConnection
        Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DEMO.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    End Function
    Private Function LoadData1() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Using con = CreateConnection(), cmd = con.CreateCommand(),
        ta = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim sql = <sql>
SELECT * From Stocks;
</sql>.Value
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            ta.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
    Private Function LoadData2() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Using con = CreateConnection(), cmd = con.CreateCommand(),
        ta = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim sql = <sql>
SELECT  
    t1.CodeProduct, t1.Barcode, t1.Colorcode, t1.[Size], 
    t1.ColorName,
    IIf(IsNull(t1.Qty),'0',t1.Qty)-IIf(IsNull(t2.Qty),'0',t2.Qty) AS QTY_STOCK,
    t1.Qty AS QTY_STOCKIN, t2.Qty AS QTY_STOCKOUT
FROM
    StocksinDetail AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    StocksoutDetail AS t2 ON (t1.[Size] = t2.[Size])
                          AND (t1.Colorcode = t2.Colorcode)
                          AND (t1.Barcode = t2.Barcode)
                          AND (t1.CodeProduct = t2.CodeProduct);
</sql>.Value
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            ta.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Datagridview1.DataSource = LoadData1()
    End Sub
```

[image: VIEW IN DATAGRIDVIEW]

[image: VIEW IN DATAGRIDVIEW]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but it seems in LoadDate2 you are using a joined query which causes the returned data-table not to be updateable. If so, maybe removing join and using calculated fields in data-table helps.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh ,actually I want to reconcile LoadData1 with LoadData2